# Question of Padj value (very high, infinite) got from dds

Tags: rna-seq, deseq2

After I got dds from my count matrix by DESeq(), I use results() method to get Padj and log2 fold changes for volcano plotting,
then I found some gene's Padj values are infinite and the P-value is very close to 0;
this makes those dots on my volcano plotting located very top to Y-aix and also confused me:

1. is this normal or not, such a p-value (very close to 0) and -logPadj is infinite;
2. how should I treat those data: are they very different expressed between samples and control or just abnormal data which should be taken off?

Here follows the table:
[image]

table 1 is dds results, -log10(padj) show inf;
table 2 is count matrix from featureCount
table 3 is size factor of samples

Please help me !

Comment: It is not normal to get p-value close to zero, especially if you have not a lot of samples. If I look at your table 2, the mean counts don't tally with the genes in table 1... so can you sort this out

Comment: there are some instances, for example you knock out or over-express a gene, then of course you find this insanely differentially expressed..

Comment: The SE are really low in this case though, rather than huge LFC. Very consistent gene expression?

Comment: For log(0) error add an arbitrarily small number to the 0 p.adj values (e.g.10^-99)

Comment: @StupidWolf Thank you StupidWolf and Greg for answer my question. I didn't list all the samples out, and one of the compounds has the opposite effect from the others, like: d has a positive effect on empty control, and a b c has a negative effect on empty control; According to the answers, I think this may cause the so much differentially expressed(but i'm not so sure).

Comment: what is being tested in this table? Hey our answers are as good as guesses if you just show a table. It's like reading the oracle from bones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The fold changes for those are huge (on the order of 32x for the largest), so it's unsurprising for the adjusted p-values to be absurdly small.
2. There's no reason to treat them differently.

Comment: Agreed. If you want to get rid of `Inf` you can add a tiny number to the pvalues before the conversion, e.g. `p + .Machine$double.xmin`.